# How to find adjacency matrix given a set of links and edges in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I have vector of all edges for example

```
A = [1;2;3;4];
```

I also have the matrix of all the links connecting these edges represented by the edge numbers for example

```
B = [1 3;3 1;1 2;1 2;2 3;4 3];
```

I would like to construct the adjacency matrix with this data. The matrix should not consider the ordering of the edges in the links For example the second link has edges 1 2 but the matrix should have entries in both 1,2 and 2,1. 
So therefore i need an output like this

```
C = [0 1 1 0;1 0 1 0;1 1 0 1;0 0 1 0];
```

I cannot think of any other way other than using a for loop for the size of B and then finding the egdes for each link in B and then adding 1's to a pre-initialized 4x4 matrix at i,j where i,j is the link edges.

Is this an efficient way because my real size is many magnitudes greater than 4? Could someone help with a better way to construct the matrix?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`sparse`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to build the matrix, and then optionally convert to [`full`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html):

```
result = full(sparse(B(:,1), B(:,2), 1)); % accumulate values
result = result | result.'; % make symmetric with 0/1 values
```

Equivalently, you can use [`accumarray`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
result = accumarray(B, 1); % accumulate values
result = result | result.'; % make symmetric with 0/1 values
```

For `A = [1;2;3;4]; B = [1 3;3 1;1 2;1 2;2 3;4 3]`, either of the above gives

```
result =
  4×4 logical array
   0   1   1   0
   1   0   1   0
   1   1   0   1
   0   0   1   0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But i have made a few changes to the question. I need the matrix to have an entry irrespective of the order of the links.

Comment: You say _The matrix should not consider the ordering of the edges in the links_ But then how do you know which order to use for each edge? Will you ever have more than two occurrences of an unordered edge? And if there is only one occurrence, should the order be inverted or not? I mean, given `B = [1 3; 1 2]` should the result be `C=[0 1 1]`, or `C=[0 0 1;1 0 0]`,  or...?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. By ordering I meant the description of the link in terms of edges. So if `B = [1 3;1 2]` , the other description `B = [3 1;2 1]` should also be considered to construct `C`. So in this case `C = [0 1 1;1 0 0;1 0 0]` . What i need is if there is a link between a pair of edges the matrix should contain a 1 for (i,j) and (j,i) . Hope this has made it clear!

Comment: Does this work with other inputs as well? Because using the inputs `A = [102; 230; 56; 42] and B = [102 56;56 102;102 230;102 230;230 56;42 56];` i get the follwoing error!  **Error using sparse
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.**

Comment: @EyesOfÖzil I had interpreted desired size incorrectly. Please try now with edited answer